# Exc_Bad_Access Exception on creating database in Iphone

Tags: objective-c, database, exception

i receive this exception after calling the following method. And it only comes when app load for the first time. When i again open the app it works fine. Can anyone help?

```
-(void) createAndCheckDatabase
{
  BOOL success; 

  self.databaseName = @"database.db";
  NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
  self.databasePath = [[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName]retain];

  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath];

  if(success) return; 

  NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName];

  NSError *err;
  [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil];
  if (err) {
//      DebugLog(@"%@", [err description]);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you paste/show us the property: self.databaseName ? what is it? retain?

Comment: @JonasSchnelli yes its retain

Comment: This like make a memory leak: `self.databasePath = [[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName]retain];` remove the `retain`. But the crash should not come from there. Did you step through the method with the debugger? where does it crash?

Comment: there is no crash log coming even after enabling NSZombie. Also it crashes just after method calling is completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if (err) ... will crash because err is not initialized! and you dont use it in fileManager copyItemAtPath:

Comment: it not initialized means is not set to nil?

Comment: Error would be initialized to nil if you are using ARC. Otherwise it is "undefined", and will probably be a garbage value. Worse, it is likely to be 0 in Debug builds, and may be a different value when running in the Simulator vs a device.

Answer (score 1):

`EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` almost always means either a bug dealing with pointers or C-arrays, or an object was over-`release`ed.

The good news is that you should have a stack-trace in the Debugger (if running in Xcode), or a crash log, that shows exactly what went wrong. (How to [gather](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1747/_index.html) and [read](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html) crash logs).

"Profiling" your code with the Zombies instrument is the best way to get more information about over-releases.

If you can post a symbolicated stacktrace, we can try and give you a better diagnosis.